# Error when checking target: expected 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 6)

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, keras, valueerror

I'm working on re-purposing a signal classifier.

My train and validation generators feed batch arrays of `[32, 3000, 1]` into the model (32 signals, 3000 time steps, flattened). 
basic_model encodes each signal to a vector 1D vector before seq_model maps this vector to a class.

To get an idea of architecture, the code to build the model can be seen below.

```
def basic_model():
    inp = Input(shape= (3000, 1))
    img_1 = Convolution1D(16, kernel_size=5, activation=activations.relu, padding="valid")(inp)
    img_1 = Convolution1D(16, kernel_size=5, activation=activations.relu, padding="valid")(img_1)
    img_1 = MaxPool1D(pool_size=2)(img_1)
    img_1 = SpatialDropout1D(rate=0.01)(img_1)
    img_1 = Convolution1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation=activations.relu, padding="valid")(img_1)
    img_1 = Convolution1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation=activations.relu, padding="valid")(img_1)
    img_1 = MaxPool1D(pool_size=2)(img_1)
    img_1 = SpatialDropout1D(rate=0.01)(img_1)
    img_1 = Convolution1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation=activations.relu, padding="valid")(img_1)
    img_1 = Convolution1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation=activations.relu, padding="valid")(img_1)
    img_1 = MaxPool1D(pool_size=2)(img_1)
    img_1 = SpatialDropout1D(rate=0.01)(img_1)
    img_1 = Convolution1D(256, kernel_size=3, activation=activations.relu, padding="valid")(img_1)
    img_1 = Convolution1D(256, kernel_size=3, activation=activations.relu, padding="valid")(img_1)
    img_1 = GlobalMaxPool1D()(img_1)
    img_1 = Dropout(rate=0.01)(img_1)

    dense_1 = Dropout(0.01)(Dense(64, activation=activations.relu, name="dense_1")(img_1)) # Last layer in basic_model gives Outputshape (None, 64)

    base_model = models.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=dense_1)
    opt = optimizers.Adam(0.001)

    base_model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy, metrics=['acc'])
    #base_model.summary()
    return base_model


def seq_model():
    nclass = 6

    seq_input = Input(shape=(None, 3000, 1))
    base_model = basic_model()

    encoded_sequence = TimeDistributed(base_model)(seq_input)  #Input shapes (0,64) (None, 3000, 1)
    encoded_sequence = SpatialDropout1D(rate=0.01)(Convolution1D(128,
                                                               kernel_size=3,
                                                               activation="relu",
                                                               padding="same")(encoded_sequence))
    encoded_sequence = Dropout(rate=0.05)(Convolution1D(128,
                                                               kernel_size=3,
                                                               activation="relu",
                                                               padding="same")(encoded_sequence))   
    #out = TimeDistributed(Dense(nclass, activation="softmax"))(encoded_sequence)
    out = Convolution1D(nclass, kernel_size=3, activation="softmax", padding="same")(encoded_sequence)

    model = models.Model(seq_input, out)

    model.compile(optimizers.Adam(0.001), losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy, metrics=['acc'])
    model.summary()
    return model

model = seq_model()

batch_size = 32 
EPOCHS = 25

ch_model = model.fit_generator(generator(X_train, y_train, batch_size), steps_per_epoch= (X_train.shape[0]//batch_size, epochs = EPOCHS,
                               validation_data= validation_generator(X_val, y_val, batch_size),
                               validation_steps=(X_val.shape[0] // batch_size), shuffle=True)
```

Running this code gives the error:

`ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 3000, 1)`

Checking model.summary() - `input_23(InputLayer) Output shape: (None, None, 3000, 1)`. Trying to change seq_input to `Input(shape=(3000,1))`, I get the error `"Input tensor must be of rank 3, 4 or 5 but was 2"`. So 1 None is used to fulfill the tensor rank requirement and from documentation the other is essentially a placeholder for batch size.

Learning this I next tried reshaping my training inputs from the generators. I did this by using `X_train = np.expand_dims(X_train, axis=0)` to give an input array of [1,32,3000,1].

This got me almost through the model but I get the error message `Error when checking target: expected conv1d_161 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 6)`. (*conv1d_161 is the output layer of seq_model.*)

My question is how can I format my batch arrays to work with this setup? Following on, what is the dimension I'm missing?

Thanks for your time:)

Answer (score 0):

In your **basic_model**, you are returning base_model which is nothing by that time. you should return ***basic_model***.
*check return statement of basic_model() function*

one more thing try using different name, you created a function basic_model inside of which you again write *basic_model = models.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=dense_1)*.

### editing for second issue.

see your output of basic model at the end is of shape **(None, 64)**

```
Model: "model_3"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_7 (InputLayer)         [(None, 3000, 1)]         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_40 (Conv1D)           (None, 2996, 16)          96        
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_41 (Conv1D)           (None, 2992, 16)          1296      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_15 (MaxPooling (None, 1496, 16)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
spatial_dropout1d_15 (Spatia (None, 1496, 16)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_42 (Conv1D)           (None, 1494, 32)          1568      
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_43 (Conv1D)           (None, 1492, 32)          3104      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_16 (MaxPooling (None, 746, 32)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
spatial_dropout1d_16 (Spatia (None, 746, 32)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_44 (Conv1D)           (None, 744, 32)           3104      
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_45 (Conv1D)           (None, 742, 32)           3104      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_17 (MaxPooling (None, 371, 32)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
spatial_dropout1d_17 (Spatia (None, 371, 32)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_46 (Conv1D)           (None, 369, 256)          24832     
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_47 (Conv1D)           (None, 367, 256)          196864    
_________________________________________________________________
global_max_pooling1d_5 (Glob (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_10 (Dropout)         (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 64)                16448     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_11 (Dropout)         (None, 64)                0         
=================================================================
Total params: 250,416
Trainable params: 250,416
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________
```

mow look at seq_model,

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_10 (InputLayer)        [(None, None, 3000, 1)]   0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_1 (TimeDist (None, None, 64)          250416    
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_67 (Conv1D)           (None, None, 128)         24704     
_________________________________________________________________
spatial_dropout1d_25 (Spatia (None, None, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_68 (Conv1D)           (None, None, 128)         49280     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_17 (Dropout)         (None, None, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_69 (Conv1D)           (None, None, 6)           2310      
=================================================================
Total params: 326,710
Trainable params: 326,710
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

your sequence model is expecting input shape of **(None, 3000, 1)** (see in seq model) , but you are passing input as **(None, 64)** (which is output of basic model), and I can't see any transformation of basic model output shape aligned to input of seq_model, hence the issue.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, when I renamed the models to make it clearer for this post I overlooked that. Do you have any ideas on why my last layer in seq_model is expecting 3 dimensions?

Comment: check the revised answer for the dimension mis-match issue.

Comment: No but it is now better understood (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60646209/issues-reshaping-numpy-array-using-ellipsis). The issue was with the shape of my input data, when I ran this architecture with inputs of shape (batch_size, 100,3000,1) it started training, however I'm having issues reshaping the data to this format now. The paper I'm basing this off was made in python 2.7 and some of the package dependencies are proving difficult to get aligned hence why I'm sort of doing this half blind. @Raj kamal Srivastav